# How to take sum of two column of different row in same table

Tags: javascript, mysql

for example there are five col in my table and data is  in four col , I like that fifth col should hold the value of i.e sum of third and fourth col and there after in next row value of fifth col in first row should add with value of fourth col of second row

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. I order to grab all the attention your issue desserve, I think you should take some time to review the [Stackoverflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and to edit your question accordingly. For example, to provide more insights about your table structure or actual data. Or to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in SQL. What you can do is create an UNION of the table with itself and do it like that.

For example:

```
SELECT 'FIRST' AS TYPE, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 + COL5 AS SUM
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SECOND' AS TYPE, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL1 + COL2 AS SUM
```

Feel free to wrap everything around in another SELECT and sort/group, e.g.
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT...) ORDER BY COL1, TYPE;

This answer is not MYSQL specific so your mileage may vary.